# How to use R quantmod to query Taiwan Stock from google finance

Tags: r, quantmod, stocks

I would like to query Taiwan stock price from google finance.
Although I can query the same stock from yahoo finance, but the volume is wrong.
So I need to get the correct data from google finance.

This code worked for yahoo finance
    getSymbols("1101.TW", src = "yahoo")

But when I query the same stock from google, it doesn't work because I don't know what is correct symbol.
    getSymbols("1101.TW", src = "google")
    getSymbols("TPE:1101", src = "google")
    getSymbols("TPE%3A1101", src = "google")

Here is the error message
Error in download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  : 
  cannot open URL 'ttp://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=TPE_1101&startdate=Jan+01,+2007&enddate=Jun+28,+2016&output=csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :
  cannot open URL 'ttp://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=TPE_1101&startdate=Jan+01,+2007&enddate=Jun+28,+2016&output=csv': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'

Below is the link
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=TPE%3A1101&ei=VF5xV8m4D8TBugThuojwCg

Please someone can help answer my questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This method get stock data through the csv download link, you can check the 'IBM' symbol contains a 'Download to spreadsheet' link. There is no such link on 'TPE:1101' symbol's historical data page.